# How do I fix this to avoid this key error?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
 def romanToInt(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        roman_table = {"I" : 1,
                       "V" : 5,
                       "X" : 10,
                       "L" : 50,
                       "C" : 100,
                       "D" : 500,
                       "M" : 1000}
        
        num = 0
        last = "I"
        
        for numeral in s[::-1]:
            if roman_table[numeral] < roman_table[last]:
                num -= roman_table[numeral]
            else:
                num += roman_table[numeral]
            last = num
        return num
```

When I try and run this I am getting a key error on line "if roman_table[numeral] < roman_table[last]:" but I'm not clear why I would be getting that error. What is causing this error?

Comment: `last` is initialized to `I`, so it is a valid key for roman_table.  However inside the loop you assign `last = num`, which makes `last` into a (decimal) number, so it is no longer a valid key.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seting `last` to an integer by setting it to `num` at the end of the for-loop.

Change `num` to `numeral`